# How to save assets to CloudKit sharedCloudDatabase?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I get the following error:

> An error occurred in CKError 0x6180000575b0: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2006); server message = "Cannot convert userId to dsId due to an invalid userId. Please check the format of the userId."; uuid = E843A411-D192-4435-BAC1-F52EDCA87990; container ID = "iCloud.com.example.myApp"

And my code is as follows:

```
func uploadAsset(recordType: String, fileURL: URL) {
    let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    let asset = CKAsset(fileURL: fileURL)

    let recordZoneID = CKRecordZoneID(zoneName: "Notes", ownerName: "_abcdeg")
    let record = CKRecord(recordType: recordType, zoneID: recordZoneID)
    record.setObject(asset, forKey: "file")

    CKContainer.default().sharedCloudDatabase.save(record) { savedRecord, error in
        if let saveError = error {
            print("An error occurred in \(saveError)") 
        } else {
            print(savedRecord)
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a complete swift ios newbie and had the same issue. It was caused by setting the wrong ownerName in the zone id. Use this method instead:

`let recordZoneID = CKRecordZone(zoneName: "Notes").zoneID`

Then the owner will be set to the current user.